# Take into account additional fields if count results are equal

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am currently using the following query to find a "category_id" that is used the most based on the "name" of an item.

```
SELECT Name,category_id,COUNT(*) as count
FROM ex.item
where name LIKE '%living%' 
GROUP BY category_id ORDER by count DESC;
```

However I hit situations in which the count results are equal

[image]

So I have modified my query to return the result randomly :

```
SELECT Name,category_id,COUNT(*) as count
FROM ex.item
where name LIKE '%living%' 
GROUP BY category_id ORDER by count,rand()  DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This works but I wanted to improve the query and remove the rand() altogether doing the following:

1) Take  subcategory_id into account (on the same table) into, so on the above example if category_id 550 is the most prevalent category_id being used and it has three subategory_id columns two with 800 and one with 900 then return the category_id  500 and subcategory_id  800 as the most common result.

2)Assuming that we still have the scenario per the picture above in which the count returns the same number ( even though that we included the subategory_id) , to try to use the description of the item field (in the same table) to see if the query string appears in the description field as well and if it appears in the description and name, to return the row that it appears in both as the prevalent result.

Thanks

Comment: 1.) Your above example does not contain subcategory_id. Please provide the table layout and some example data + expected result.

Comment: Are you ok with a Join?

Comment: @dognose yes because I am not using it on the existing query..I would like to use it though, updated post with table layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can group by more than one value:

```
SELECT Name,category_id, subcategory_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM ex.item
where name LIKE '%living%' 
GROUP BY category_id, subcategory_id ORDER by count DESC;
```

2) Use a CASE statement to compute a score/weight/boost that you can combine with other factors:

```
SELECT Name,case when description like '%living%' then 1 else 0 end as boost, category_id,COUNT(*) as count
FROM ex.item
where name LIKE '%living%' 
GROUP BY category_id ORDER by count DESC;
```

Stuff you didn't ask about:

- If these categories are "tied", why not take them to the one that
  makes you the most money (highest margins, highest sale percentage,
  etc)?
- If you use wildcards at the beginning of your values, the
  query can't use an index on that column.  Look into a text search
  function (MySQL has one, or go use something like
  solr/elasticsearch/cloudsearch).  This will also help you with the scoring.